# Coq : Using a parametrized Type from within a Module

Tags: coq

I'm trying to use Modules in my project and I made this small example to show what I'm struggling with.

```
Module Type A.
  Parameter t : Type.
End A.

Module a : A.
  Definition t := nat.
End a.

Module B.
  Module Import InstanceOfA := a.
  Definition x : t := 2.
  Definition sum (t1 t2 : t) : nat :=  t1 + t2.    
End B.
```

Which fails with:

> The term "2" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "t".

Basically, I have a Module Type with a parametrized Type and a Module that instantiates it. The Module is a specific implementation of the Module Type for naturals (hence t:=nat), so when I'm trying to use the module in a third-party module I want to talk about naturals using this instance.

In my real scenario, I have some coercions I want to get working. I know that if I use Nats in Module B the definitions from A would work fine, but what happens is that I obtain values of type `t` and need to treat them as type `nat`.

Is there any chance to "expose" the type equality from the module? I tried something like an identity function: `t -> nat` in `a` but it doesn't work.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Module a : A.`, which seals the module (and thus hides the definition of `t`), write `Module a <: A.`, which keeps `a`'s definition visible.